# using frenchbabel in tex

Tags: packages

As I have some french letters, I use the following package on tex ;

\usepackage[francais]{babel}

But in the article document class, for abstract and references, it gives me these words in french. What should I do in order to convert them to English ? Whatever I did, it did not work.

Comment: You don't need `babel` to typeset letters such as `é` or `à`. Can you make a small example of code?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to load `babel` if your document is in English. You can just input the French letters as `` \`e `` for “è”, `\'e` for “é” and so on.

You can even type directly the letters if you add

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

ensuring that your file is UTF-8 encoded (which most editors nowadays choose by default).

So an example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

I can easily write French words like `élève' and `voilà', which
can also be input as `\'el\`eve' and `voil\`a'.

\end{document}
```

If you need to be sure that French is hyphenated correctly, you can load `babel`, but with the English language option last:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

I can easily write French words like `\foreignlanguage{french}{élève}' and
`\foreignlanguage{french}{voilà}', which can also be input as 
`\foreignlanguage{french}{\'el\`eve}' and `\foreignlanguage{french}{voil\`a}'.

\end{document}
```

In this case, the main language is English, so all the tags will be in English too.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply use `\usepackage[french]{babel}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in your preamble. For example, with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\title{Title}
\author{Mario Bross}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
 This is just a test.
\end{abstract} 

\end{document}
```

I got this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it does not convert "Résumé" to "Abstract"... It is what I try.